# How to access the method in a ViewModel?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

i have a viewmodel:

```
public class ManageUserViewModel
{
  public Entities.User User { get; set; }
  public bool IsLockedOut { get; set; }
  public bool IsActivated { get; set; }
  public bool IsArchived { get; set; }
}
```

in  Entities.User User i have a method:

```
/// Gets the incentive programs that this user is participating in.
public IEnumerable<IncentiveProgram> GetParticipatingIncentivePrograms()
{
  return Node.ParticipatingIncentivePrograms
    .Where(x => x.PublishingState == PublishingState.Live
      && DateTime.UtcNow.Date >= x.DateStart && DateTime.UtcNow.Date <= x.DateEnd);
}
```

then i have my controller:

```
   [HttpGet]
public ActionResult UserDetails(int id)
{
  var user = ZincService.GetUserForId(id);
  if (user == null || user.Customer.CustomerId != CurrentCustomer.CustomerId)
    return DataNotFound();

  ManageUserViewModel viewModel = new ManageUserViewModel();
  viewModel.User = user;
  viewModel.IsLockedOut = MembershipService.IsUserLocked(user.Email);
  viewModel.IsActivated = user.DateTimeActivated.HasValue && MembershipService.IsUserApproved(user.Email);
  viewModel.IsArchived = user.IsArchived;
  viewModel.User.GetParticipatingIncentivePrograms();
  return View(viewModel);
}
```

how do i get to output of GetParticipatingIncentivePrograms in my view?
I dont have code in my view yet.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Imho, you'd be better representing your incentive programs in your view model.  In fact to have a userViewModel and then probably have a list of programs within this.  Then load these within your controller

```
ManageUserViewModel{
   public UserViewModel User { get; set; }
}

UserViewModel {
   public List<string> ParticipatingIncentivePrograms { get; set; }
}
```

It's usually best to not load your whole domain graph into a view as you could run into several issues (N+1 db calls, accessing a closed proxy, etc).  I've typed your programs as a simple list of names, but you might expand this to a dictionary or lookup.  Again keeping the view model as light and simple as possible.

UPDATE:

As you can't change the viewmodel then it looks like you must set the value, you are only calling at present.  So try the following

```
 viewModel.User.ParticipatingIncentivePrograms = 
        viewModel.User.GetParticipatingIncentivePrograms();
```

If there is such a collection on user or set them to something else on your view model.

Comment: Im afraid this code was written by someone else and I cannot change the architecture, i have to carry on with what i've got :)